# rabbitmq what is difference between SubscribeAsync and PublishAsync in C#

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, microservices

I'm using rabbitmq in my microservices project and I saw these two methods
what are these and when do we use each

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. We may guess.. but it's always better to provide the language tag, along with others; 2. Docs should be relatively clear, on what those two do. Have you read the docs?

Comment: That's the first time I ever saw someone code in Comic Sans. Doesn't coding in a variable width font make it hard work?

Comment: RabbitMq uses the terms publish and consume for producer / consumer respectively. IBusClient.SubscribeAsync presumably is a custom abstraction of a consumer in a package called RawRabbit.

Comment: Subscribe usually adds the additional concern of filtering or predicating messages. In rabbit you would do this via queue bindings eg on routing keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're using something on top of RMQ, like EasyNetQ, because these aren't rabbit terms specifically, but in essence:

Publish publishes messages to a queue

Subscribe subscribes to a queue and defines the code that will act on the received message

Answer (score 1):

> A producer is a user application that sends messages while a consumer is a user application that receives messages.A queue is a buffer that stores those messages.
> <sub>https://dev.to/mashaa/introduction-to-rabbitmq-49n8</sub>

> In many pub/sub systems, publishers post messages to an intermediary message broker or event bus, and subscribers register subscriptions with that broker, letting the broker perform the filtering. The broker normally performs a store and forward function to route messages from publishers to subscribers. In addition, the broker may prioritize messages in a queue before routing.
> <sub>https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish–subscribe_pattern</sub>

> The core idea in the messaging model in RabbitMQ is that the producer never sends any messages directly to a queue. Actually, quite often the producer doesn’t even know if a message will be delivered to any queue at all.
> <sub>https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html</sub>